# How to make powertop "Device Power Management" suggestion permanent?

Tags: 11.04, power-management, acpi, powertop

When I run powertop on my laptop I get following suggestion:

> Suggestion: Enable Device Power Management by pressing the P key

Doing this results in considerable saving in power usage and I would like to make it permanent but I have no idea what this option really does or how to make it permanent. Currently I have to run powertop each time I want this option enabled.